# Are the values stored in std::pair<> by reference or by value?

Tags: c++, c++17, std-pair

so I have a class `myClass` and with it two private variables, let's say i,j and a class method `myMethod` as following-

```
std::pair<int, int > myClass::myMethod(void)
{
    std::pair<int, int> Pair;
    this->i = 100;
    this->j = 50;
    Pair.first = this->i;
    Pair.second = this->j;
    return Pair;
}
```

and I am calling the method as follows from another function-

```
std::pair<int, int> receivedPair = myClass.myMethod();
```

So if I edit `receivedPair` lets say

```
receivedPair.first = 200;
```

will the Class variable `i` also become equal to 200?
I essentially need to pass the variables by reference to a couple of functions in series so that the same memory location gets updated ....
TIA

Comment: would be nice if you could remove the typos from the code. `this.i` ? no that wont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `std::pair`, in your specific case, is nothing more than, in so many words:

```
struct pair {
   int first;
   int second;
};
```

`first` and `second`, in your `std::pair`, are non-reference class members. The full definition of `std::pair` is pretty much

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> struct pair {
   T1 first;
   T2 second;
};
```

Comment: From which `template <class T1, class T2> struct refpair{T1& first; T2& second;};` is not a million miles away although references are a pain with assignment so is probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this well explained.

Comment: @Bathsheba `T1` and `T2` can just be `int&`; no need to change the def of `pair`

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I ain't so sure about that. Bad things will happen with assignment for example. Possibly above my pay grade.

Comment: The "bad thing" would be a compilation failure, since the default assignment operator gets deleted.

Comment: @Bathsheba It would still be equivalent to your example

Answer (score 7):

The values of `std::pair` are by value.

In your case though you could use

```
std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<int>, std::reference_wrapper<int>>
```

as the type.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper

Comment: Apparently, `std::pair<int&, int&>` would also work. Are there any advantages for using `std::reference_wrapper` ?

Comment: @ahmadPH A reference_wrapper is reseatable, which may or may not be important

Comment: Thank a lot @Bathsheba for replying, I went through the doc, and it does not clearly mention can it used for custom classes.. I actually need to pass OpenCV classes and Intel's real sense classes by reference

Comment: @AtharvaDubey: It will work for custom classes too. Note that it doesn't *really* wrap a reference - rather it encapsulates a pointer and gives you an operator for the implicit conversion to a reference.

Comment: @AtharvaDubey If you use this approach, you will need to call `.get()` in order to be able to modify the pair later. For example, you would have to call `receivedPair.first.get() = 200;`. simply using 'receivedPair.first = 200` would throw an error in the lines of : `use of deleted function ‘std::reference_wrapper<_Tp>::reference_wrapper(_Tp&&) [with _Tp = int]’`. I guess direct assignment is used to change the pointer, and `.get()` is used to change the content pointed to.

Comment: @Bathsheba I tried and it says - `std::pair<reference_wrapper<rs2::pipeline>, reference_wrapper<rs2::config>> pipe_and_config;` ,  same thing for cv::Videocapture and cv::Mat too.. I am using C++17 if it matters because some functions are deprecated in C++17

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided, the values are stored **by value**, since you declared the type as `std::pair<int, int>`. If you want the values to be stored **by reference**, you can do this:

```cpp
std::pair<int&, int&> myClass::myMethod(void)
{
    this.i = 100;
    this.j = 50;
    std::pair<int&, int&> Pair(this.i, this.j);
    return Pair;
}
```

P.S. I only added this answer because I thought the earlier answer with `std::reference_wrapper` wouldn't let you modify the content of the reference! And then I discovered that you can modify the content using `.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::pair` stores whatever you tell it. You could use a `std::pair<int&,int&>`. Though, references as members have some downsides. Copying, default construction and more is problematic / impossible.

Instead of using a pair of references, a reference to a pair might be easier:

```
struct myClass {
    std::pair<int,int>& myMethod() {
        return data;
    }
    private:
    std::pair<int,int> data;
};
```

I claim that if you cannot give the members better names than `i` and `j`, then `data.first` and `data.second` is as good. On the other hand, if you can give better names, then do so:

```
struct my_i_and_j {
    int some_meaningful_name;
    int another_meaningful_name;
};

struct myClass {
    my_i_and_j& myMethod() {
        return data;
    }
    private:
    i_and_j data;
};
```

However, note that returning a non-const reference to private data breaks encapsulation. Once the caller got the non-const reference they can directly modify the private data and you could/should actually make it public for less boiler-plate and more clarity.